# Books/References for Inequalities that take advantage of orders

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, inequalities, textbook-recommendation, books

Are there any good references/papers/books that specifically address inequalities that take advantage of orders or monotonicity? I have already browsed through the classical *Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class* by Steele as well as *Inequalities* by Hardy, Littlewood, and Polya, and while they were amazing books, I wanted to dive deeper. Thank you very much!!

---

Answer (score 8):

Two such books are [Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68276-1) by Marshall, Olkin, and Arnold and [Stochastic Orders](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387329154) by Shaked and Shanthikumar.

Answer (score 5):

There is also Barry Arnold's [Majorization and the Lorenz Order: A Brief Introduction](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387965925?) published in the Springer Lectures in Statistics series.